# How to apply functions sequentially with purrr and pipes

Tags: r, dictionary, iteration, purrr

I am struggling with the purrr package.

I am trying to apply the function `is.factor` to a data frame, and then `fct_count` on those columns that are factors.

I have tried some variations of `modify_if`, and `summarise_if`. I guess I am using incorrectly the dots (.) when calling for the previous object.

(A guide about purrr, and dots would be really beneficial if you have a link).

For example,

```
df <- data.frame(f1 = c("men", "woman", "men", "men"), 
                 f2 = c("high", "low", "low", "low"), 
                 n1 = c(1, 3, 3, 6))
```

Then

```
map(df, is.factor)
```

If I use

```
map_if(df, is.factor, forcats::fct_count)
```

I got results for every variable, instead of only for the factors.

I think it is a pretty simple problem, and with a bit of understanding of the dots (.) can be solved.

Thanks in advance
:)

Comment: What is your expected output? I suspect this is due to `stringsAsFactors` being `TRUE`. Otherwise, the result seems clear to me.

Comment: Try `df %>% mutate_if(is.factor, list(~list( fct_count(.)))) %>% unnest`

Comment: Thanks for the help. Akrun, would you mind referencing a site where I can learn more about the purrr package (how to use the dots the ~list,  the unnest, and others. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue is that `map_if` returns the unmodified columns as well.  Hence, when the OP tries the code (repeating the same code as in the OP just to show)

```
map_if(df, is.factor, forcats::fct_count)
#$f1
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  f         n
#  <fct> <int>
#1 men       3
#2 woman     1

#$f2
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  f         n
#  <fct> <int>
#1 high      1
#2 low       3

#$n1
#[1] 1 3 3 6  ### it is the same column value unchanged
```

Here, we can specify the `.else` and `discard` the NULL elements. So, if we specify the other columns to return `NULL` and then use `discard` the `NULL` elements, it would be a `list` of factor counts.

```
library(tidyverse)
map_if(df, is.factor, forcats::fct_count, .else = ~ NULL) %>%
       discard(is.null)
#$f1
## A tibble: 2 x 2
#  f         n
#  <fct> <int>
#1 men       3
#2 woman     1

#$f2
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  f         n
#  <fct> <int>
#1 high      1
#2 low       3
```

---

Or another option is `summarise_if` and place the output in a `list`

```
df %>% 
      summarise_if(is.factor, list(~ list(fct_count(.)))) %>%
      unclass
```

---

Or another option would be to `gather` into 'long' format and then `count` once

```
gather(df, key, val, f1:f2) %>% 
        dplyr::count(key, val)
```

---

Or this can be done with `lapply` from `base R`

```
lapply(df[sapply(df, is.factor)], fct_count)
```

Or using only `base R`

```
lapply(df[sapply(df, is.factor)], table)
```

Or the results can be represented in a different way

```
table(names(df)[1:2][col(df[1:2])], unlist(df[1:2]))
```

Comment: I think `OP`'s code is correct except they assumed a modification was made although: `modify_if() only modifies the elements of x that satisfy a predicate and leaves the others unchanged.` I think they should use `keep` first.

Comment: @NelsonGon  Yes, you are right.  `map_if` makes other columns unchanged.  I am assuming that if the OP wants to only return those columns, instead of the whole dataset

Comment: ``` 
map_if(df, is.factor, forcats::fct_count, .else = ~ NULL) %>%
       discard(is.null) ```
@akrun
This one worked perfectly, and I can use it for future code. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue with `map_if`/`modify_if` is it applies the function to only the columns which satisfy the predicate function and rest of them are returned as it is.

Hence, when you try

```
library(tidyverse)  
map_if(df, is.factor, forcats::fct_count)

#$f1
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  f         n
#  <fct> <int>
#1 men       3
#2 woman     1

#$f2
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  f         n
#  <fct> <int>
#1 high      1
#2 low       3

#$n1
#[1] 1 3 3 6
```

`fct_count` is applied to columns `f1` and `f2` which are factors and column `n1` is returned as it is. If you want to get only factor columns in the output one way would be to `select` them first and then apply the function

```
df %>%
  select_if(is.factor) %>%
  map(forcats::fct_count)

#$f1
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  f         n
#  <fct> <int>
#1 men       3
#2 woman     1

#$f2
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  f         n
#  <fct> <int>
#1 high      1
#2 low       3
```

Comment: Yes, you are right Ronak. I could have found this solution with a bit more searching. Thanks for the help =)